# Distinguish between Windows 8 web browser and app user agent

Tags: windows-8, user-agent

I am trying to use Reg-ex on user agent to identify Windows 8 requests. What is the best way to distinguish between App Request/Browser Request? What differences do I look for in the user agent string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdeveloperpreviewgeneral/thread/6be392da-4d2f-41b4-8354-8dcee20c85cd/) should help to construct your regex

Comment: Thank you so much! The link definitely helps. However, could i treat IF(UserAgent.Contains("MSAppHost") == True as App and the rest as Browser?

Comment: I did not see "MSAppHost" anywhere in user-agent strings. Could you please point me to that. Secondly, unless client is requesting with raw http requests you may not know if it is from app. Because webview/webbrowser controls emulate browser.

Comment: Here is the link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534712(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If the request comes from windows store apps written in HTML5/JS, then only you will get "MSAppHost" in the user-agent string. If it is originated from other kinds of apps (like windows store apps with C#/XAML, desktop apps) then user-agent string will not contain that string. "The process that hosts and executes a Windows Store app using JavaScript is called WWAHost.exe" from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465143.aspx. This process adds up "MSAppHost" to the user-agent string.

Comment: I am trying to identify at least all the "native" Windows Apps (Search App etc.). I guess, Contains("MSAppHost") should work fine for the same.

Comment: Cool. Keep your progress posted, it may help people on the same path as you are.

Comment: It’s interesting to note that there is a difference in agent strings when building an app with C# vs JavaScript. The agent string changes from WebView to MSAppHost. This is due to the fact that in Xaml apps the content is presented in a control that renders HTML whereas in HTML apps it’s just an area with different sandbox rules.

See https://jaredbienz.wordpress.com/2014/05/14/whats-my-apps-agent-string-well-that-depends/